# What does valgrind mean by "Warning: client syscall munmap tried to modify addresses"

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

We have a fairly complex multi-threaded linux program that does some heavy number crunching on CUDA devices after data has been acquired from an ADC.

Just running some sanity checks on it, and we get several occurrences of:

```
 ==16577== Warning: client syscall munmap tried to modify addresses 0x0-0x5ffffffff
```

while the application is starting up under valgrind.  I haven't been able to track down where these are coming from, as there are no line numbers or any other specific identifiers associated with them.  Nor do we directly call munmap anywhere.

I also can't find any indication online as to what these warnings mean, or whether they're a problem?

Do they indicate a problem with our app?

Comment: This might sound a little dumb, but one way to identify error-generating source code line(s) in environments without a debugger (such as within valgrind) is by inserting puts("0"), puts("1"), puts("2"), etc. statements throughout the code in a divide-and-conquer fashion, narrowing down to the location where valgrind emits the warning message. Maybe you tried that already :-/